# code style and testing in pre-commit, only last exit value stop the pre-commit

Tags: githooks, pre-commit-hook

for check [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (python code style) and test, in the pre-commit git hook I have this

```
#!/bin/sh
flake8 *.py tests
python setup.py test
```

a fail in test stop the commit but a error in code style no.

If I change to

```
#!/bin/sh
flake8 *.py tests && python setup.py test
```

work fine, why pre-commit don't stop with the first exit code 1 ?

Comment: I have a similar issue.

Comment: The script exits with the value of the last executed command.  If the last command succeeds, then the script succeeds.  If you want the script to abort early, it must check the status of each command and act accordingly.  (Very simple to do this with `set -e`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your script exit on error:

```
  #!/bin/sh

  set -e

  ...
```